# Is it safe to replace a Hyundai air flow sensor with Nissan?

Tags: nissan, hyundai

When I try to accelerate my car (a 2000 Hyundai Accent 1.3L hatchback), it gave some misfires and tries to stop the engine.

My mechanic said it is due to an airflow sensor failure, and that he can fix it using an airflow sensor off a Nissan FB 15. According to him, both sensors are identical except for the pins. So he is trying to fix that manually.

Does this sound correct? Is it okay to replace a Hyundai airflow sensor with a Nissan one?

Comment: It could also be due to a faulty coilpack or spark plug. Get another opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Personnaly I would go with an Hyundai sensor since it's made and calibrated for your vehicule. Does the Hyundai and Nissan part are the same price new? If so, why using / hacking a Nissan sensor as the other one is plug an play?

That being said, if you proceed with the Nissan sensor, make sure you remember the fix as if a problem arise later on it can be related on the manual fix.